# String Value is the name of an int pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, dereference

```
struct token{ string type; string value;};

//Global variables:
int reg[10]={-1,...,-1};
int* R0 = reg;

... down in some func...
cout<< *(R0)<< endl;//OUTPUTs -1
int valInR0= *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&token.value) //contains string "R0"
```

The issue is that I have a struct that has a member of string called value to store different names and when I try to take the name of an int pointer out of the string I am unable to figure out how to make it reference back to the int pointer and dereference its value.

As in the above example taking the string val "R0" out of my struct and then using it to access the int *RO is what I am trying to accomplish to no success.

Comment: You cannot do that, symbols aren't available at runtime.

Comment: For this kind of thing you probably want to use a [std::map<std::string, int>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: `int valInR0= *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&token.value)` This makes no sense. Don't use cast and pointers for hiding compiler errors. Your answer `int val = (token.value[1]-ASCII)` could also go wrong. Maybe you mean to declare `int value` instead of `string value`.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Thank you. I'm pulling the int value from the set of string values "R0","R1"..."R7" which are stored in the token.value member of my struct.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers, what I decided was to manipulate the name, so if R5 is stored I rip off the R, Store the 5 in an int, and can then use it for an offset to access the value like `*(reg+5)`, like so:

```
int val = (token.value[1]-ASCII);// ASCII is 48
```